# Is there any way to designate content off-limits to browser's built-in text searching?

Tags: html, css, browser

I've got a page that I want easily searchable using the browser's built-in search function (command/control-F). I've got some text in a `textarea` that I don't want the in-browser search function to get hung up on. How can I designate this content as not searchable by the browser's in-page search? Is there perhaps a CSS attribute I can set?

NB: I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19457994/html-can-you-hide-ignore-text-elements-from-browser-find-ctrlf), but pseudo-elements are not possible solutions.